# Creating Views using node-couchdb module

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-futon

As I am new to CouchDB, I wanted to create the view using a node-couchdb module?

I am able to create a view using UI(Futon), but I want to create a view using node code using a node-couchdb module.
Also, how can I add a design document?
Is adding document and design document same?

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create views or design document using **node-couchdb** module as:

```
couch.insert(_dbname, {
    "_id": "_design/query-demo",
    "views": {
        "full-name": {
            "map": "function (doc) {  emit(doc._id, doc);}"
        }
    },
    "language": "javascript"
});
```

Here in this example, **full-name** will be the view name and **query-demo** will be the design doc name

And we can get the data from that view as:

```
couch.get(_dbname, '_design/query-demo/_views/full_name', {}).then(({ data, headers, status }) => {
    console.log(data);
    // data is json response
    // headers is an object with all response headers
    // status is statusCode number
}, err => {
    console.log(err);
    // either request error occured
    // ...or err.code=EDOCMISSING if document is missing
    // ...or err.code=EUNKNOWN if statusCode is unexpected
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A CouchDB Design Document is just another document except its `_id` field starts `with`_design`.

You can create a Design Document by simply inserting it as any other document using the official [Apache CouchDB Nano](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano) library:

```
const Nano = require('nano')
const nano = Nano('http://localhost:5984')
const db = nano.db.use('mydb')

const ddoc = {
  "_id": "_design/report",
  "views": {
    "bydate": {
      "reduce": "_count",
      "map": "function(doc) {\n  if (doc.type === 'click') {\n emit(doc.x, doc.y);\n  }\n}"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}

db.insert(ddoc, function(err, data) {

});
```